# Raspbian uses the complete dhcp range

Tags: raspbian, dhcp, ipv4

I temporarily had a static ip for my raspberry. Now the config looks like this.

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

But this leads to a reservation of the complete range of the availble dhcp ips.

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:94:90:82 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.29/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.30/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.31/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.32/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.33/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.34/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.35/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.36/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.37/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.38/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.39/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.41/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.42/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.43/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.44/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.45/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.40/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.46/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.47/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.49/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.50/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.51/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.52/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.53/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.54/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.55/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.56/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.57/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.58/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.59/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.60/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.61/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.62/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.63/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.64/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.65/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.66/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.67/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.68/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.69/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.70/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.71/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.72/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.73/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.74/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.75/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.77/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.78/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.79/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.80/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.81/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.82/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.83/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.84/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.85/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.86/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.87/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.88/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.89/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.90/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.91/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.92/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.93/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.94/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.95/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.96/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.97/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.98/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.99/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.100/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.101/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.102/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.103/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.104/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.105/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.106/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.107/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.108/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.109/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.110/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.111/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.112/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.113/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.114/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.115/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.116/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.117/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.118/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.119/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.120/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.121/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.122/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.123/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.124/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.125/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.126/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.127/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.128/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.129/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.130/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.131/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.132/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.133/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.134/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.135/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.136/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.137/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.138/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.139/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.141/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.142/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.143/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.144/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.145/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.146/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.147/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.148/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.149/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.150/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.151/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.152/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.153/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.154/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.155/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.156/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.157/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.158/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.159/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.161/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.162/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.163/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.164/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.165/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.166/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.167/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.168/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.169/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.170/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.171/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.172/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.173/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.174/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.175/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.176/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.177/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.178/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.179/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.180/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.181/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.182/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.183/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.184/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.185/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.186/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.187/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.188/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.189/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.190/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.191/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.192/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.193/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.194/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.195/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.196/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.197/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.198/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.200/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.199/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.24/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.26/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.27/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.28/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

What is the problem?

(Raspbian GNU/Linux 8)

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

There is not a problem.

### Explanation

That output simply states that any IP Address in the range from 192.168.2.24 to 192.168.2.200 is available for lease.  Note that 192.168.2.25 and 192.168.2.199 are missing from the range.  This implies that your raspbian and another device have obtained those 2 addresses already.

Your assumption is correct, the entire pool is reserved, as in all the addresses are available to be used.  Think of it this way:

Lets go to your favorite restaurant and tell the hostess we want a table for 2.  Assuming the restaurant was empty, if we said we even wanted 2 tables, the hostess would give us 2 of the reserved tables, but in reality the whole restaurant is "reserved" for us and the other paying customers.  This results in a reservation of the "whole range of tables."  The hostess is aware that the entire range is available, just like DHCP is aware of the range of available addresses.

Comment: That's not how it's ever worked on any of my machines.  In fact, a "scope global secondary" address is just another way of having an alias IP address on an interface - i.e. the rpi has all of those IPs as its own IPs and will listen to and respond to packets sent to those addresses (for all services specifically listening to those addresses or listening to ALL addressses).  See http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-address.html.  In other words, there IS something wrong with the rpi's config.  This http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13359/where-does-my-secondary-ip-come-from may help.